# How could a "global implicit class" be defined in Scala?

Tags: scala

Considering that a implicit class "must be defined inside of another trait/class/object"[1](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html), how can a implicit conversion be defined globally?

The case is that I'd like to add a method to all `Strings` (or `Lists`) in my application, or at least to several packages of it.

Comment: Predef is imported implicitly, so just supply a custom Predef with your implicit.

Comment: I like this idea, any links on how to create a custom Predef? i can't seem to find such a thing...

Comment: They give you `-Yno-imports` and `-Yno-predef` to turn it off, but no easy way to customize it. I would copy the src Predef.scala and put it on my classpath before scala-library, but that's tricky depending on your build tool (or add it to scalac script). Or, just use a custom local build of scala, which is not impossible; sbt supports that.

Answer (score 4):

One cannot add anything to the "global" scope, neither in Java, nor in Scala.
However, in Scala one can define `package objects`, which can contain methods that are used all over the package, and can be easily imported by the user.

This looks something like this: in the directory `foo/bar/baz` one creates a file called `package.scala` with the following content:

```
package foo.bar

package object baz {
  implicit def incrediblyUsefulConversion(s: String) = ...
}
```

The user then can do the following in his code to activate the conversion:

```
import foo.bar.baz._
```

or maybe

```
import foo.bar.baz.incrediblyUsefulConversion
```

Of course, you can also use your own code in other packages, just like any other user.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, if i have to copy this code in every package i want to use this conversion, which can be a lot... i was considering if this would be the case for a macro...

Comment: You are not supposed to copy code. This is what packages and `import` statements are for. Moreover, if you add this code to multiple packages, you get implicit conversion precedence conflicts all over the place (this is why implicits are tricky). Macros are a completely other kind of animal, they are kind of like lisp-macros for compile time, don't know why you would need them here.

Comment: What i'm trying to find out is how to avoid repeating the import code itself, "import foo.bar.baz.incrediblyUsefulConversion", in every file (for pimping strings, lists and tuples)...

Comment: Suppose you can get rid of this single `import` line. What remains? 0 lines? This would mean that 0 lines of code somehow trigger the inclusion of every implicit conversion that has been ever written. This would be just one gigantic implicit-conversion conflict. And if you maintain code, you *really* want to see all the places where a conversion can come from: this is why implicit conversions defined somewhere in the corresponding classes are such a nightmare to debug: one doesn't see them in the code. So every import line is helpful.

Comment: I agree with you generally, but in this specific case, to add methods to a highly used type, such as String, it would be nice to be able to define a custom Predef for the compiler instead of adding a redundant import in *every* file.

Comment: Well, then you have to either rewrite Predef (breaks compatibility with standard lib), or write some kind of compiler plugin (which would mean that your code becomes useless without the plugin), or maybe just prepend a code-generation step to you build, which adds the "import mylib._" everywhere. However, I can not understand how a single `import` statement would possibly justify creation of a custom compiler plugin. `awk BEGIN{print "import foo._"} {print $0}` has essentially the same effect, but costs you only 10 seconds to type.

Comment: On usage side, each time a "import foo.bar.baz._" is perfectly minimal. Nicely explained! Thank You a lot